# Subquery returned more than 1 value. please help. i beg for mercy

Tags: sql-server, subquery

This is may table. In one column there are daily dates and in the other is a classification.

[image]

I use this query to count how many registers are in a month and which ones are `C` or `D`, but the subquery can only return one value . How can i fix it?

```
select FORMAT(fecha, 'yyyy-MM') as FECHAS, COUNT(*) as TOTAL,
(select count(tipo) from prueba where tipo = 'C' group by FORMAT(fecha, 'yyyy-MM')) as CREDITO,
(select count(tipo) from prueba where tipo = 'D' group by FORMAT(fecha, 'yyyy-MM')) as DEBITO
from prueba
where fecha >= '01-08-2014'
group by FORMAT(fecha, 'yyyy-MM')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify which database you were using, but in most databases, you can use a `CASE` expression inside the `COUNT` aggregate function to accomplish your goal:

```
select FORMAT(fecha, 'yyyy-MM') as FECHAS,
       COUNT(*) as TOTAL,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN tipo = 'C' THEN 'X' END) as CREDITO,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN tipo = 'D' THEN 'X' END) as DEBITO
from PRUEBA
where fecha >= '01-08-2014'
group by FORMAT(fecha, 'yyyy-MM')
```